# Implementing licensing mechanism for Applications Distributed in App store

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore, license

I have an app that I intend to distribute via the App store.
Currently, the user purchases a license from the website, he receives a key via email and our web server validates the license key entered by the user in the application.
Is it possible to distribute the app in the App Store without any change ie:the user purchase on app store,he receives a key.

Can i distribute the trial version as free on App store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Licensing Schemes

No, applications can not use their own key based licensing system with purchases being handled by Apple's App Store.

See Apple's [Validate app and in-app purchase receipts with the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts) documentation about how to handle App Store purchases and the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1).

> See [WWDC 2018 > Engineering Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/) for more information on implementing receipt validation for apps that contain auto-renewable subscription products.

Apple does not provide licensing sample code. Apple fear that if everyone uses the same implementation, it becomes trivial to bypass. If you need code level help, contact Apple and use a [Technical Support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/).

## Trials

Apple does not accept free trials in the App Store. Applications must have value that does not expire. In-app purchases can be used to unlock additional features. See [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

Comment: Can you please point me to some articles on how to check if the app was purchased from the app store in a macOS app ie: Validation

Comment: See [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1)

Comment: There are no examples in the guide.What validation you perform? Local or Online? Seems local validation is complex.Can you guide me with some SWIFT sample code.

Comment: I have added Apple's **Engineering Subscriptions** link.

Comment: How can i get the app with the receipt for testing ?

Comment: See **Fetch the Receipt Data** in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store

Comment: My app does not have a receipt as it is not downloaded from App store.How to generate the receipt for testing purpose.

Comment: Please contact Apple directly for [code level technical support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/). It is their store and they must support developers.